# Ranking specific elements within a data structure - is the a more efficient way?

Tags: java

I am ranking certain groups of elements within a .csv file. My program works. However ...

I am seeking advice on on how to improve the efficiency of a program I have written. I do not seek a review of my code. [Stackoverflow ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266713/how-to-ask-is-this-good-practice-or-is-there-a-better-solution-than). Nor I am requesting someone to write code for me. All I am asking is: "Is there a more efficient way? and if so what?"

I have a program that takes multiple .csv files, modifies them and adds extra data. These files are then saved. Below is a respresentation of the input data:

```
ISBN, Shop, Cost, ReviewScore,
9780008305796, A Bookshop, 11.99, 4.8,
9781787460966, A Bookshop, 6.99, 4.3,
9781787460966, Lots of books, 5.99, 4.4,
9781838770013, A Bookshop, 6.99, 3.8,
9780008305796, The bookseller, 13.99, 4.7,
9780008305796, Lots of books, 16.99, 4.1,
```

Note: each .csv file is normally 1000's of lines long. There could be 1 to 20 instances of an ISBN. The .csv is not ordered by any column.

My program works as follows (pseudocode):

1. load csv into String[][]
2. iterate through String[][] to create a map: with k = ISBN, v = number of occurances of that ISBN
3. iterate through String[][]
   3.1 get the ISBN value from map then save each line that has that ISBN (stop when value reached)
   3.2 then rank the price and reviews of saved lines, and save the lines into another var.
   3.3 delete key
   3.4 go back to 3. until there are no keys
4. save into .csv

data will now look like:

```
ISBN, Shop, Cost, ReviewScore, CostRank, ReviewRank
9780008305796, A Bookshop, 11.99, 4.8, 1, 1
9781787460966, A Bookshop, 6.99, 4.3, 2, 2
9781787460966, Lots of books, 5.99, 4.4, 1, 1
9781838770013, A Bookshop, 6.99, 3.8, 1, 1
9780008305796, The bookseller, 13.99, 4.1, 2, 3
9780008305796, Lots of books, 16.99, 4.3, 3, 2
```

This program does not depend on the type of data structure the .csv is loaded into. It could be a List, List of Lists, Collection etc.

Comment: A dataframe library seems like it would be ideal for this type of task. Have you tried using one?

Comment: Could you explain how the ranks are calculated?

Comment: If you're asking us to improve the efficiency of your program, it might be helpful to see what you have so far. Do you have a working program? Do you have metrics to tell you where it's spending the most time?

Comment: What are you optimising for? Speed? Memory?

Usually the only optimisation that really matters is to make the code easier to understand. Java is rather punishing for this since you often need to create interim objects. 

As @GreenCloakGuy suggested you might want to try something like Python's Pandas library. There the logic would be: Build a table -> Group by ISBN -> Aggregate. It's generally easier to follow.

Comment: Hello. @GreenCloakGuy. I have not tried using a dataframe library in Java, I have limited exerience of Pandas in python. I am looking into it now.

Comment: Hello @AndrewVershinin  I cant find the stackoverflow question that I used, but here is the code: `code` private void getRankMap(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);

        Collections.sort(listCopy);
        this.rankMap = new HashMap<>();
        int counter = 0;
        for(int x : listCopy) 
        {
            this.rankMap.put(x, counter); 
            counter++;
        }
    } `code`

Comment: Hello. @Matthew. I would like to think I am moving from beginner Java to intermediate Java skills. What I am trying to do is make as few iterations as posssible. By doing so, I hope to learn a bit more.

Comment: Hello @rajah The program is too big to post the code.I haven't timed any of the program. I feel that I am iterating far more than I should because I dont know the techniques to do better

Comment: @combatwomble Why do you need the number of occurences map? I would suggest just creating a copy with two extra columns, using `System.arraycopy` to copy the existing data, calculate ranks the way you do, iterate over said copy and fill the rank columns.

Comment: The number of occurences is there to restrict the number of iterations. Say the are 5 instances of ISBN 123456, the progam 'knows' this because of the map, so after its found the 5th instance it stops looking and moves onto the next key. If I hadn't of put this in then the program would iterate through all lines for every key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You /could/ do it in a single pass, the code would look something like so:

```
  Map<String, IsbnData> dataStore = new HashMap();
  forEach(row : rows) {
     IsbnData datum = dataStore.get(row[0]); //or whatever the index of ISBN is
     if(datum == null) {
        datum = createIsbnDataFromRow(row);
     } else {
        datum = updateDatumWithMoreData(datum, row);
     }

     dataStore.put(row[0], datum);
  }
```

The main benefit of this is that instead of having to deal with `String[]` you have nicely structured classes and the code is easier to read.

The code /may/ run faster, but that's probably irrelevant since it's much more likely to run out of memory before the speed matters. (Don't confuse this with the program being slow - it may well be slow, but that is due to reading / parsing the CSV files. The speed gain from passing over the CSV files less times after you've parsed them is negligable).

Comment: Thank you @Matthew. It took me a while to do (new things to learn e.g. I had never seen or used Map<String, "A Class I Have Made">). I do think this is a better way. I also noted your comment "Don't confuse... is negligable" and is something I will use whilst coding.